# Pegar a primeira letra do nome e do último sobrenome?

Tags: java

Estou usando o código abaixo para pegar a primeira letra do nome e sobrenome.

Está funcionando, mas eu vejo o seguinte problema para um nome mais extenso:

Exemplo:

> Carlos Eduardo Martins Dutra do Rego

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String nome = "Carlos Eduardo Martins Dutra do Rego";
    String primeiraLetraNomeSobrenome = "";
    for (char letra : nome.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(letra)) {
            primeiraLetraNomeSobrenome += letra;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("resultado: "+ primeiraLetraNomeSobrenome);
}
```

Recebo: CEMDR

Queria pegar a primeira e a última ficando **CR**. Teriam alguma dica pra eu resolver isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para pegar a primeira letra do último nome você pode usar o método `lastIndexOf()` da classe `String`:

```
String nome = "Carlos Eduardo Martins Dutra do Rego";
int posicaoUltimoEspaco = nome.lastIndexOf(" ");
String primeiraLetraUltimoNome = nome.substring(posicaoUltimoEspaco + 1, posicaoUltimoEspaco + 2);
```

Ao fazer `nome.lastIndexOf(" ")`, será retornada a posição do último caractere espaço.

Então:

```
String primeiraLetraUltimoNome = nome.substring(posicaoUltimoEspaco + 1, posicaoUltimoEspaco + 2);
```

- `posicaoUltimoEspaco + 1` : A posição do último espaço é o caractere espaço em si. Somo `+1` para pegar a partir do próximo caractere.
- `posicaoUltimoEspaco + 2` : Continuando o raciocínio do item acima, adiciono `+2` para indicar que quero até o próximo caracetere.

---

Para pegar a primeira letra do primeiro nome basta fazer:

```
String nome = "Carlos Eduardo Martins Dutra do Rego";
String primeiraLetra = Character.toString(nome.charAt(0));
```

---

### EDIT

O método `lastIndexOf()` retorna `-1` caso não encontre nenhum registro da String procurada. É necessário fazer uma pequena verificação antes:

```
int posicaoUltimoEspaco = nome.lastIndexOf(" ");
String primeiraLetraUltimoNome = "";
if(posicaoUltimoEspaco > 0) {
    primeiraLetraUltimoNome = nome.substring(posicaoUltimoEspaco + 1, posicaoUltimoEspaco + 2);
}
```

Comment: Se o nome for só **"Carlos"**, a saída vai ser **C C**. Está certo isso?

Comment: @jbueno alterado

Comment: @IgorVenturelli obrigada pela didática que me ajudou muito.

Comment: Eu ainda não entendi, se o nome for só **Carlos** a saída deve ser uma string vazia?

Comment: @jbueno não. Essa foi a implementação mais simples que encontrei, uma vez que o foco da pergunta é identificar as iniciais e não a concatenação em si. A forma correta/elegante seria fazer a concatenação com `StringBuilder` e só chamar o `append()` se o resultado de `lastIndexOf()` for `>0`.

Answer (score 6):

Particularmente eu facilitaria muito seu código, desta maneira. Obviamente você precisa validar se a string recebida não está nula ou vazia, mas isso é só detalhe, o foco aqui é a implementação.

```
String nome = "Carlos Eduardo Martins Dutra do Rego";
String[] array = nome.split(" ");
// ^ Cria um array onde cada elemento é uma das palavras

String resultado = String.valueOf(array[0].charAt(0));
// ^ Captura a primeira letra da primeira palavra do array    

if(array.length > 1)
    resultado += array[array.length - 1].charAt(0);
    // ^ Captura a primeira letra da última palavra, apenas se tiver mais de uma palavra

System.out.println("resultado: "+ resultado);
```

---

Se quiser apenas complementar o seu método atual, só é necessário obter o primeiro e último carácter da string produzida com `charAt(0)` e `charAt(tamanhoDaString - 1)`.

```
String nome = "Carlos Eduardo Martins Dutra do Rego";
String primeiraLetraNomeSobrenome = "";
for (char letra : nome.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(letra)) {
        primeiraLetraNomeSobrenome += letra;
    }
}

String primeiraUltima = primeiraLetraNomeSobrenome.charAt(0) + 
                primeiraLetraNomeSobrenome.charAt(primeiraLetraNomeSobrenome.length() -1);

System.out.println("resultado: "+ primeiraUltima);
```

Comment: O algoritmo é ingênuo, várias coisas podem dar errado, mas não é problema seu, o que foi perguntado está respondido, o primeiro está um pouco melhor, pra fazer um robusto seria ainda mais complexo.