# Qual o comando do Java que me retorna os caracteres maiusculos?

Tags: java

Por exemplo, "Jorge Aragão Silva" ai me retorna "J A S"

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse link [aqui](http://www.guj.com.br/t/mostrar-iniciais-donome/94021)

Comment: Essas respostas [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5725949/6754506) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193241/54152)

Comment: Agora se você quer tirar somente as iniciais de cada palavra tem esse [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28461995/6754506) e esse [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26181091/6754506)

Comment: Mas os espaços são para retirar ou incluir ?

Comment: Ainda estou em dúvida. Se é para retornar caracteres maiúsculos, então para "JOSÉ DA SILVA", teria que retornar todas as letras? Mas parece que vc quer só as iniciais do nome, então deveria ser "J D S"? Ou ainda "J S", pois geralmente o "DA" não conta como iniciais do nome. E vc manteve os espaços, então não é para retornar **somente** os caracteres maiúsculos, certo? Se puder **[edit]** a pergunta deixando mais claro o que você precisa, com mais alguns exemplos etc. Aproveite para conhecer melhor o site e como devem ser feitas as perguntas, lendo o **[tour]** e a página **[ask]**.

Answer (score 4):

No título da pergunta está para pegar apenas as letras maiúsculas das palavras. No exemplo no corpo do texto tem espaçamentos, mas estou com o [@André Filipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/343206/64969).

Você pode usar expressões regulares para remover as letras não maiúsulas:

```
String nomeCompleto = "Jorge Aragão Silva";
return nomeCompleto.replaceAll("\\P{Lu}", "");
```

O método [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) da string no Java vai fazer a substituição de toda parte que casar com o padrão (primeiro argumento) pelo substituto. O padrão que eu passei foi `\P{Lu}`.

> [Leia mais sobre padrões](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Ele consiste no padrão negado da propriedade `Lu`. O que isso quer dizer? Basicamente, se uma letra estiver dentro do padrão `Lu`, ela será ignorada; caso contrário, caso esteja em `Lu`, ela casará com o padrão e, portanto, sofrerá substituição.

O padrão `Lu` são as letras Unicode maiúsculas. Portanto, tudo que não for Unicode maiúsculo será removido.

Se eu desejasse um padrão que satisfizesse a propriedade `Lu`, eu usaria `\p{Lu}` com **`p`** minúsculo mesmo. O **`P`** maiúsculo indica que a propriedade descrita *{entre chaves}* será negada.

Na substituição, coloquei dois contra barras `\\` por questão de como o Java trata a contra barra em strings. Então, se eu escrever `\\n`, o Java entenderá que eu quis digitar a string `\n`. Já `\n` o Java interpreta como quebra de linha. Para dizer explicitamente ao Java que eu desejo uma contra barra `\` e um `P` maiúsculo, usei `\\P`.

Fontes que me auxiliaram:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20661766/4438007
2. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36312533/4438007
4. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Boa Jefferson, ótima resposta mestre!

Answer (score 3):

```
String nomeCompleto = "Jorge Aragão Silva";

StringBuilder iniciaisEmMaiusculo = new StringBuilder();
for (char letra : nomeCompleto.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(letra)) {
        iniciaisEmMaiusculo.append(letra);
    }
}
return iniciaisEmMaiusculo.toString(); //Retornará a String "JAS"
```

Bons estudos!

Comment: para que serve esse char letra?

Comment: Nesse contexto o tipo de variável char serve para pegar cada caractede do nomeCompleto.

Comment: @Ruan, esse `for` aí é conhecido como `foreach`. Esse laço do André Filipe é lido desse jeito: _"para cada caracter `letra` dentro de `nomeCompleto.toCharArray()`, faça..."_

Comment: Exato @JeffersonQuesado, valeu grande!

Comment: Se não me engano, `StringBuilder` tem o método `append`, e não `add`

Comment: @hkotsubo [verdade](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Answer (score 2):

Usando o for após o split você consegue

Dá uma olhada

```
 String x = "Shojibur rahman";
 String[] myName = x.split(" ");
 String saida = "";
 for (int i = 0; i < myName.length; i++) {
    String s = myName[i].toUpperCase();
    saida += s.charAt(0)+" "; 
 }
 System.out.println(saida);
```

Espero ter ajudado

Teste rápido [aqui](https://javafiddle.leaningtech.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo simples

```
       String nome = "Jorge Aragão Silva".toUpperCase();
       String iniciais = "";

       for (int i = 0; i < nome.length(); i++){
            char caractere = nome.charAt(i);        

            if(i == 0)
                iniciais+=caractere;

            if(caractere == ' ')
                iniciais+=nome.charAt(i+1);
        }
```